# How to install Illustrator CS6 on Precise?

Tags: installation, adobe

I am trying to install Illustrator CS 6 on 12.04. I know it is possible, because there are some screenshots and movies over internet showing that some of people succeeded. However I did not.
I am willing to use even CrossOver if necessary. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly, a better solution would be to install Windows in a VirtualBox and CS6 on top of it.

Comment: Yes, but this way has some major disadvantages.

Comment: Sure, as well as advantages. I use VBox to run MS Office which I need for compatibility purposes, and it integrates very nicely with the rest of my system through use of shared folders.

Comment: @January when he talks about disadvantages, he must be talking about performance, which will be degraded when run from a vm.

Comment: @NlightNFotis Given that vbox supports hardware virtualization, the performance hit is actually pretty unnoticeable. In fact, MS Office on Windows 7 on Vbox is more reactive and faster than native LibreOffice on my 4 yr old system. Admittedly, it eats memory like a dinosaur, but with 4GB or more you will not even notice that.

Comment: @January yes my friend, but I am afraid I will have to disagree. Ms office is CPU dependent and doesn't use GPU acceleration at all. Adobe products on the other hand, are on a whole new league (GPU-heavy workload)

Comment: @NlightNFotis well, you have a point here, just don't you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously do not think that you might be able to run any product from the Adobe Creative Suite 6 **natively into linux**.

Even to be able to run this kind of software, you will need to use software such as ***wine***. But even this way, software like Adobe Creative suite 5 are known to have severe issues, so great as to render them unusuable at times, so I wouldn't bet on Adobe cs6 to run properly. **[EDIT]:** *Actually [this](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26011) suggests that it is usable, marking it with a Silver rating, however I wouldn't take it's word for working professionally with it.*

If I were in your shoes, I would keep a Windows machine, **or** (as @January suggested) if I couldn't spare one, I would use a  virtual machine. Please keep in mind that a virtual machine will have a great performance hit when you compare it with a physical machine, especially when workloads involve heavy GPU usage.

**[EDIT #2]:** To be more accurate as why you will have a performance hit using a virtual machine, first of all you have to note **that the virtual device emulating the GPU is never able to emulate the GPU on its full potential**, meaning you only get a fragment of its power. Additionally, **the virtual device can use only a percentage of the GPU's RAM** so, this is not going to help you with applications that do heavy usage of the GPU's RAM.